# Storing Action<T> in a Stack<T> for UndoManager

Tags: c#, delegates, stack

I want to keep track of all property changes on a class. I thought could keep track of each event by pushing each "undo" operation on to stack of Action Delegates. When Undo() is called, get a refrence to the last Undo Event and invoke it, however this 
does not seem to work. Also when I try to pop() the last Action off the stack, its not removed from the stack.

Perhaps this is not the best approach? This is just a learning process for me on Delegates, so maybe my approach is wrong.

Example:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.Value = "Test1";
Console.WriteLine("Add 1.{0}", mc.Value);

mc.Value = "Test2";
Console.WriteLine("Add 2.{0}", mc.Value);

mc.Undo(); 

Console.WriteLine("Undo: {0}", mc.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Stack size: {0}", mc.MyOperations.Count);

public interface IUndoManager<T>
{       
    void Add(Action<T> undoOperation);       

}
public class MyClass : IUndoManager<MyClass> {

    public Stack<Action<MyClass>> MyOperations {get;set;}

    private String value;
    public String Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }

        set {
            this.Add(x => this.Value = value);
            this.value = value;

        }
    }

    public void Add(Action<MyClass> undoOperation)
    {
        this.MyOperations.Push(undoOperation);
    }

    public void Undo() { 

        Action<MyClass> lastAction = this.MyOperations.Pop();
        lastAction(this);// fire event

    }

    public MyClass() {

        this.MyOperations = new Stack<Action<MyClass>>();        
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
public String Value
{
    get { return this.value; }

    set
    {
        this.Add(x => this.Value = value);
        this.value = value;

    }
}
```

Specifically the line:

```
this.Add(x => this.Value = value);
```

Here undoing the value calls the property setter *which adds another operation to the stack*.

In this case you want to access the underlying value, not the property, to avoid this:

```
this.Add(x => this.value = value);
```

As for design issues, I wouldn't expose the stack publicly, nor would I expose the `Add` method publicly.  Those should each be internal implementation details of the type.  Having callers messing with either could cause problems.

This is why it seemed that you couldn't ever shrink your stack.  Calling `Undo` wasn't "not popping off the value", it was simply popping the value, and then putting a new one back on to replace it.

Also note that you keep track of `Action<MyClass>` rather than just `Action`, but when actually adding actions you don't ever use the parameter.  If you are going to have the stack of actions accept a parameter then use the parameter rather than closing over `this`.  If you are going to use the closure anyway, you might as well just remove the parameter form the method and simplify things.

It also probably makes sense for `IUndoManager` to have an `Undo` operation.  (In fact, I don't even see why it needs an `Add` operation; the `Undo` is what should be called externally).

Comment: Over use of this always indicates an issue somewhere in my experience. Got to agree with you one exposing the stack. mc.MyOperations = new Stack<Action<MyClass>>(); would be baaaad.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Everything about it is bad.  You can clear the stack, you can pop off an action without invoking it to essentially erase just a part of the history, you can add items without changing the object so that undoing actually does a new operation, which won't be undone, etc.  Literally anything done with it externally is badness, except possibly checking the count.

Comment: Yep, but public MyOperations {get; private set} would be one step in the correct direction. Like you I can't imagine why you'd want to be able to push extra items on to the stack outside of the logic in the class. Didn't like that value business at all. A real killer would be when someone comes along and says I'd like to redo. :(

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Having a private setter doesn't help you at all.  An external user can still do *everything* that I described in my previous comment.  If you want users to be able to `Redo` then add a `Redo` method.  To do it you'll need a second stack, anytime anything is ever undone, you need to push an undo of that undo onto the redo stack.  You also need to clear the redo stack whenever `Add` is called.  The redo stack should also not be exposed publicly at all.

Comment: @Servy As a note, I made the Add method private as suggested. I am now going to work on the redo stack.

Comment: @Servy I know,  but all that pales in to insignificance when you can assign a completely different stack to it as well, so it does help, not a whole hell of a lot, but a bit...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Not really.  If you have a reference to the stack you can just call `Clear` on it, or pop off all of the values.  Being able to change which `Stack` is being referenced is actually not any worse than calling `Clear`, as there aren't any other (legitimate) references to the stack.

Comment: Way simpler than that in the original code mc.MyOperations = null. Busted, dead, gone, stuffed, pining for the norwegian fjords...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson You think `mc.MyOperations = null` is radically different than `mc.MyOperations.Clear()`?

Comment: Yeah you can still push to a cleared one with mc. What are we arguing about anyway? Pohtatoes and potahtoes this.